# Remove Cookie issue

Tags: gwt, cookies, token

I have a cookie save a token when a user logs into www.example.com and then it redirects them to example.com/desktop or example.com/mobile depending on what device they're using. When they log out of the desktop app I replace the cookie with null and then call remove cookie in GWT and redirect them to www.example.com, but the cookie still exists. Am I doing something wrong here? I haven't worked with cookies much before so I'm a bit new to this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the cookie was set at another *path*, you have to use `Cookies.removeCookie("cookieName", "/")` (`/` being the path used in your example) and not `Cookies.removeCookie("cookieName")`.

This is because without a specified path, the path defaults to the one of the current page (see [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)).

So, you're trying to remove the cookie at path=/desktop, whereas it's actually at path=/, so the removal fails.
Remember that you could have two cookies with the same name but different paths; so you could have a *cookieName* at `path=/` *and* a _*cookieName* at `path=/desktop`. Removing the cookie at `path=/` won't remove the one at `path=/desktop`, and conversely, removing the one at `path=/desktop` won't remove the one at `path=/`.
As a side note: when accessing `/desktop`, the browser would send both cookies, which could have different values.

In brief, because you set your cookie at `/`, remember to always pass `/` as the path, everywhere, or you could create a new cookie rather than modifying the existing one, or fail to remove it (which you're experiencing right now).

See also [`Cookies.removeCookie(String,String)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html#removeCookie%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies the behavior I was getting. I definitely found that if I removed the cookie from the original path that it was successfully removed. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

In case you also need a non-default domain use

```
public static native void removeCookie(String name, String path, String domain) /*-{
    $doc.cookie = name + "=" + ((path) ? ";path=" + path : "")
            + ((domain) ? ";domain=" + domain : "")
            + ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
}-*/;
```

Comment: This one certainly gives a solution while the accepted answer does not.