# Cookies not removing by Cookies.removeCookie("cookieName") in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, cookies

Scenario:

I am setting Cookies in page https://www.example.com/#step1 by using method:

```
Cookies.setCookies("firstFileName","NewDocument");
Cookies.setCookies("firstFileExt","doc");
```

Users are supposed to click next and redirect themselves to https://www.example.com/#step2 . But in Case, user click to some other menu (like Home, About us, Contact us), I am deleting these Cookies by using the following method:

```
Cookies.removeCookie("firstFileName");
Cookies.removeCookie("firstFileExt");
```

But on removing I found that these two Cookies still holding the values in browser, When I do the following in https://www.example.com/#step1 before setting these two Cookies:

```
if(!Cookies.getCookie("firstFileName").toString().equals("undefined")){
        Window.alert("firstFileName "+firstFileName);
    }
```

I get an alert box that `firstFileName NewDocument`

Please let me know how can I set and remove the Cookies in my Case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049467/remove-cookie-issue

Comment: @OviFaur How could I set a path for token type URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a cookie without providing a path, as you do using `Cookies.setCookies("firstFileName","NewDocument");`, the cookie can only be removed on the same page.

A solution would be to always set the cookie for a specific path like that:

```
// TODO: set expiration time to something more useful
Date expires = new Date();
Cookies.setCookie("firstFileName","NewDocument", expires, null, "/", false);
```

Then you can remove it by calling that later on:

```
Cookies.removeCookie("firstFileName", "/");
```

As your application is based on the relative path "/", every page can set or remove the cookie and all pages access the same cookie value.
If you just set the cookie without providing a path, two pages of your application could even set different cookies.